# Twitter Typeahead/Bloodhound Suggestions from Ajax-Source: how manage multiple values?

Tags: javascript, typeahead.js, typeahead, bloodhound

I'm using typeahead/bloodhound for suggestions pulling from an ajax source:

```
var protags = new Bloodhound({  
datumTokenizer: function(protags) {
return Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace(protags.value);
},
queryTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace,
remote: {
url: '/ajax/getinfo.php?q=%QUERY',
wildcard: '%QUERY',
filter: function(response) {     
return response.protags;
}
}
});
```

JSON result from getinfo.php looks like this:

```
{
"protags": [
{"tag": {
"tagid": "1",
"tagtitle": "titleone"}
},
{"tag": {
"tagid": "2",
"tagtitle": "titletwo"}
},
{"tag": {
"tagid": "3",
"tagtitle": "titlethree"}
}]}
```

I'm able to retrieve all the information i want (tagtitle AND tagid) and display it using:

```
$('.typeahead').typeahead(
{ hint: true,
highlight: true,
minLength: 1
}, 
{
name: 'protags',
displayKey: function(protags) {
return protags.tag.tagtitle+'-'+protags.tag.tagid;
},
source: protags.ttAdapter()
});
```

But i'm confused about that: how can i display just the tagtitle in the suggestion field, but getting the protags.tag.tagid as well for more serverside actions?

Comment: do you want to use the data after user makes a selection?

Comment: yeezzz: yes, that's exactly what i want

Comment: try my answer... I forgot about the suggestion field so I 'll edit in a minute

Comment: sorry, but i can't make it work within my typeahead block :-(

Comment: well maybe you can post a fiddle?

Comment: argh, got it - and saw that you're already mentioned the problem: 
on('typeahead:select' vs. on('typeahead:selected'
thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the :select event (v 0.11.x), or :selected event (v.0.10.x). Read the bloodhound/typeahead docs as they made a lot of changes between 0.10.x and 0.11.x

I'm using 0.10.5 and in my case it looks like this:

EDIT: looking at your json, I'm not sure what data goes into template and :selected function. You may need to use data.protags.tag etc

```
$(selector).typeahead(
    // options, key, source etc

    templates: {
        suggestion: function (data) {
            return '<div class="tt-name">' + data.tag.tagtitle + '</div>';
        }
    }
    // end of options
)
.on('typeahead:selected',
    function(event, data) {
    // you should be able to get your data here, if I'm correct like so:
    console.log(data.tag.tagid);
   }
);
```

Comment: everyone, take care of your typeahead version as yeezzz mentioned above!

.on('typeahead:selected' vs. .on('typeahead:select'